# chef kitchen not working from Windows 10 integrated bash

Tags: linux, bash, windows-10, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I am receiving the following error when trying to run any command in 'kitchen':

```
bash: /mnt/c/opscode/chefdk/bin/kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

It works from outside integrated bash when using the chefdk client, however I am trying to get this working from integrated bash.

Chef utility commands such as 'chef-client' and 'knife' seem to be working  so far.

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux runs Linux executables. Is there a `/usr/bin/ruby` file?

Comment: It....looks as if...it is somehow trying to run a windows install of chef?  Have you tried `sudo apt install chef`?  Sorry if you have and this is super obvious to you :)

Comment: Yeah i have tried that and it ask me to autoremove it as it recognizes that chef is already installed.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick ```ruby``` file does exist in that dir

Answer (score 2):

[A possible solution for the SSH key permissions issue below](https://superuser.com/a/1329702)

We REALLY need to get this working all the way through because it is SO much faster than the native ChefDK on Windows!  The below will get you closer:

1. Stop Windows From Sharing PATH with WSL

   - Use `Regedit.exe` to create a DWORD `DistributionFlags` with value `fffffffd` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LxssManager`. Then go to Services and restart the `LxssManager` service.
2. Download and install ChefDK and Vagrant for Ubuntu in WSL
3. Add some windows paths to your WSL Path

   `export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/d/bin/Oracle/VirtualBox:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0"`
4. Allow Vagrant Windows Access

   `export VAGRANT_WSL_ENABLE_WINDOWS_ACCESS='1'`
5. Run `kitchen converge` and it now works
6. Running `kitchen login` still has issues.  It complains about insecure vagrant private key:

   `/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.22.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:217: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/dgames/.yadr/bin in PATH, mode 040777
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
   @         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
   Permissions 0777 for '/mnt/k/20180707-mbp/repos/github/cloud/ssl_certs/.kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/all-cacerts-centos-72/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key' are too open.
   It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
   This private key will be ignored.
   Load key "/mnt/k/20180707-mbp/repos/ge_github/cloud/ssl_certs/.kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/all-cacerts-centos-72/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key": bad permissions
   vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:`

Answer (score 1):

We haven't set things up to work with WSL as the Windows ChefDK installers are native Windows-y builds of everything. I recommend using the bash from MSYS2 if you want that as a shell.